# How would I make a checkered pattern using a for loop in MATLAB for a user inputted dimension?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Basically the problem I can't solve is how to adapt into a for loop so depending on whatever dimensions I am given it does it on its own. This is an example using 2x2 dimensions. So for example if was to do 3x3 how would I do it in a for loop?

```
N=4; 
R=2;
theta=zeros(1,N);
for k=1:N
    theta(k)=2*pi*(k-1)/N;
end

x1=(R*cos(theta+pi/4)/sqrt(2));
y1=(R*sin(theta+pi/4)/sqrt(2));
plot(x1,y1);
fill(x1,y1,'w');



x2=(R*cos(theta+pi/4)/sqrt(2))+R;
y2=(R*sin(theta+pi/4)/sqrt(2));
plot(x2,y2);
fill(x2,y2,'y');


x3=(R*cos(theta+pi/4)/sqrt(2));
y3=(R*sin(theta+pi/4)/sqrt(2))+R;
plot(x3,y3);
fill(x3,y3,'y');


x4=(R*cos(theta+pi/4)/sqrt(2))+R;
y4=(R*sin(theta+pi/4)/sqrt(2))+R;
plot(x4,y4);
fill(x4,y4,'w');
hold;
```

Comment: What is your question? You forgot to ask one. Please [edit] the question containing an actual question statement. See [ask] on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a grid of points using `ndgrid` (or `meshgrid`).
To create index for the checker pattern, one trick is to use `invhilb`.
Below I used constant `x` and `y` instead of the one you created from `R*cos(theta+pi/4)/sqrt(2)`

```
% User input
N = 4;

% Basic square index
x = [0 1 1 0];
y = [0 0 1 1];

% Create axes and set to 'hold'
axes('NextPlot','Add')

% Create grid
[X,Y] = ndgrid(0:N-1);

% Loop over grid
for idx = 1:numel(X)
    fh(idx) = fill(X(idx) + x, Y(idx) + y, 'w');
end

% Color as a check board (but with yellow)
set(fh(invhilb(N) > 0),'FaceColor','y')
```